# Replace using SED + Vars + New Line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I'm trying to use a "sed" with new line, but I want to use this new line in a var like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
var1='tags'
var2='aw1 \n
aw2 \n
aw3'

sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s@'"$var1"'@'"$var2"'@g' *.html
```

I want to repĺace a pattern `tags` in my document to a many lines inside my `var2`.

```
BEFORE:
tags


AFTER
aw1
aw2
aw3
```

Comment: `:a;N;$!ba` reads many lines. Do you need this? In your example are those blank lines after `tags` deliberate? As if you wanted to replace many lines with many lines. But `var1` is not multi-line, so it's not really clear. Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, it should be as simple as replace every ENTER with "\n". Like:

`sed "s/tags/aw1\naw2\naw3/g" file`

Do not use both (ENTER and \n). Let me know if I understood the problem.

and... I just forgot: If you need to put it in a variable, you should "double escape" the \n. Like

`v=tags;
c=aw1\\naw2\\naw3;
sed "s/$v/$c/g" *.html`

Comment: It’s (IMHO) simpler to put the string in quotes; i.e., ``c='aw1\naw2\naw3'`` or ``c="aw1\naw2\naw3"``.